# Mysql join with group by and order by

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, greatest-n-per-group

I am using this mysql query

```
SELECT `p`.`id` AS product_id, `p`.`title` , `i`.`image` , `u`.`user_username` , `m`.`id` AS message_id, `m`.`date` , `m`.`from` , `m`.`to` , `m`.`message` , `m`.`read`
FROM (`messages` AS m)
JOIN `products` AS p ON `m`.`product_id` = `p`.`id`
JOIN `users` AS u ON `m`.`from` = `u`.`user_id`
JOIN `product_images` AS i ON `p`.`id` = `i`.`product_id`
WHERE `i`.`type` = 'FRONT'
AND (m.to = '1171' OR m.from = '1171)
GROUP BY `m`.`therad_user` , `m`.`product_id`
ORDER BY `m`.`id` DESC
```

In message table it shows message with oldest message id, I want to return latest message. but it show oldest message. how I solve this.

Comment: Greatest n per group didn't help?

Comment: yes i serch about it ther are subquery solution but  subquery solution  is for different table not main table

Comment: So, just focus on the 'different' table for now.

Comment: i solve this using one more query to get last message form thread and replace from first message in array

Comment: yes but i am not going to stop think about this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ORDER BY first, then only GROUP BY

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT `p`.`id` AS product_id, `p`.`title` , `i`.`image` , `u`.`user_username` , `m`.`id` AS message_id, `m`.`date` , `m`.`from` , `m`.`to` , `m`.`message` , `m`.`read`
FROM (`messages` AS m)
JOIN `products` AS p ON `m`.`product_id` = `p`.`id`
JOIN `users` AS u ON `m`.`from` = `u`.`user_id`
JOIN `product_images` AS i ON `p`.`id` = `i`.`product_id`
WHERE `i`.`type` = 'FRONT'
AND (m.to = '1171' OR m.from = '1171)
ORDER BY `m`.`id` DESC
) tmp
GROUP BY `m`.`therad_user` , `m`.`product_id`
```